# Why create a facade in laravel instead of calling a method directly?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I'm just starting with laravel and want to understand this...

Lets say we have a class in our application:

```
namespace App\Tests;
class MyTest{

    public function sayHello($name){
        echo "Hello, $name!";
    }

    public static function anotherTest(){
        echo "another test...";
    }

}
```

What is the advantage of creating a facade and a service provider over just using it as

```
use App\Tests\MyTest;

//... controller declarations here ....

public function someaction(){

    $mt = new MyTest();
    $mt->sayHello('John');

    //or
    MyTest::anotherTest();

}

//... etc...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades) in Laravel is only a convenient way to get an object from the [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container) and call a method on it.

So calling a Facade like this :

```
//access session using a Facade 
$value = Session::get('key');
```

Is like doing:

```
//access session directly from the Service Container
$value = $app->make('session')->get('key');
```

As the Facade resolves the `session` key out of the Service Container and call the method `get` on it

Once understood what a Facade does, you should understand what is the Service container and what are the benefits of using it

The Service Container in Laravel cloud be a Dependency Injection Container and a Registry for the application

The advantages of using a Service Container over creating manually your objects are stated in one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37039108/3739901) and in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container) page, but briefly:

- Capacity to manage class dependencies on object instantation
- Binding of interfaces to concrete classes, so that when a interface is requested in your program, a concrete class is instantiated automatically by the service container. Changing the concrete class on the binding, will change the concrete objects instantiated through all your app
- Possibility to create single intances and get them back later (Singleton)