# What does 'this followed by square brackets' mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I found one code block in Laravel like below:

```
/**
 * Register a "before" application filter.
 *
 * @param  \Closure|string  $callback
 * @return void
 */
public function before($callback)
{
    return $this['router']->before($callback);
}
```

What does `$this['router']` mean at here? Can anyone explain the `$this['xx']` form? Is it an array?

Comment: Yes it can be an array or in this case, probably an object

Comment: Usually denotes a key in an array

Comment: The class probably implements `ArrayAccess` (http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)

Comment: Here's an example which demonstrates the behaviour: https://3v4l.org/Q2Lhi

Comment: Yeah! You are right! I'm just looking for what you said. Thank you very much! @naththedeveloper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that your variable is called `$this` means that it can't be an ordinary array - that variable name is reserved for the current instance of a class.

Using square brackets to access an object is a sign that the class implements that [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface - that is, it can be accessed using the operators normally reserved for basic arrays.

Retrieving a value from a class that implements `ArrayAccess` using square bracket notation invokes the class's `offsetGet` method, with the provided key as the `$offset` argument. The most common use is to allow access to a class's member variables, but the class itself can choose to perform any action in this method.

In your case, I think you're looking at the Laravel application class, which will result in the *router* item being returned from the dependency injection container.

Answer (score 2):

`$this['router']` references to router service in laravel service container.
A service container (or dependency injection container) is simply a PHP object that manages the instantiation of services (i.e. objects).

see : 
[What is the concept of Service Container in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038830/what-is-the-concept-of-service-container-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that it is an array. You use the square brackets, with a key (which can be a name (string, wrapped in quotes), or a number) to identify the proper value from the array.

In your code, `$this['router']` refers to an array that contained in the class you are looking at, and that is the identifier to select what it needs, `router` being the key.